# useEffect is calling itself even when the page is closed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, e-commerce, use-effect

I've been dealing with this issue for a while, I have an useEffect that calls an api to register an order, so far so good, the thing is that this method is executing itself again even if the user closes the webpage so that leads to a repeated registration of that order (this issue can happen even days after the first registration)

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        return await axios.post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}${
            orderClass.link
          }`,
          {
            checkoutInfo,
            objectOrderInfo: orderInfoParsed,
            orderTotal,
            date: new Date().toISOString(),
            discountCode,
          }
        );
    }
    dispatch(deleteAllFromCart());
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

i don't use the await before calling fetchData because i dont need to wait until the api response, if someone knows what this issue maybe be please let me know :) thx

Comment: it's tough to diagnose this without seeing more of your code. is it possible this component is somehow re-mounting?

also, have you considered dispatching after you make the axios call? something like `fetchData().then(response => dispatch(deleteAllFromCart())`

Comment: It shouldn't be re-mounting and actually thats the main code of the component, the issue is happening in production, i haven't been able to reproduce it while testing, and also its so weird because my clients receive a clone order days after the first order, its like its calling itself randomly even if they don't open the browser

I would consider your advice with .then() :), thx

Comment: fwiw, it's a bit odd to see this kind of API call in `useEffect()`. a more common approach would be to trigger your `post` request from an `onClick` event from a button.